# Target Unreachable, identifier resolved to null

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Quando tento abrir a página, recebo:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: pagina.xhtml @3,54 value="#{meuManagedBean.valores}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'meuManagedBean' resolved to null
```

Considerando:

```xhtml
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel id="formulario" value="#{meuManagedBean.label}"/>
    <p:selectOneRadio id="grupo" layout="custom" value="#{meuManagedBean.valores}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Verdadeiro" itemValue="true"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Falso" itemvalue="false"/>
        <p:ajax event="keyup" update="formulario"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>
    <p:panelGrid columns="4">
        <p:radioButton for="grupo" itemIndex="0"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="Verdadeiro"/>
        <p:radioButton for="grupo" itemIndex="1"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="Falso"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Por que o erro se dá apenas na EL do `p:selectOneRadio` e não do `p:outputLabel`? Como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro acontece porque o `meuManagedBean` simplesmente não existe nesse caso. Possivelmente faltou alguma anotação na classe para indicar que essa classe deve ser um bean gerenciável ou simplesmente o nome do bean está errado. Os nomes dos beans são case-sensitive, ou seja, há diferença entre um bean chamado `MeuManagedBean` e outro chamado `meuManagedBean`.

Sobre o erro ser disparado apenas no `selectOneMenu`, isso depende muito da implementação do JSF que você está usando (Mojarra, MyFaces), pois cada age de forma diferente, porém o que acontece é que o XHTML é transformado em uma árvore de componentes, e por algum motivo esta entrada está sendo executada primeiro que o `outputLabel`. Para efeito de teste, deixe apenas o label no XHTML. Você obterá o mesmo resultado, pois só haverá ele para ser executado.

Comment: Estou usando Mojarra. Deixei apenas a EL do outputLabel e funcionou. O `meuManagedBean` está com as anotações apropriadas e o nome também está correto. Existe alguma implicação especial por se tratar de um selectOneMenu?

Comment: @Patrick A lista está nula? Ela tem que estar instanciada.

Comment: Receio que não, pois é um booleano (`Boolean valores;`).

Comment: @Patrick Acredito que o tipo de dado correto a ser usado com um `selectOneRadio` no value é uma String, não um boolean, conforme aponta o exemplo do Primefaces no showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml

Comment: Isso influencia em algo? Pois eu quero que quando "verdadeiro" for selecionado, seja true, quando "falso" for, seja false.